# Did Homelander bring Billy to his wife in the comics and why?

Tags: the-boys

In the TV series, season 1 of The Boys Homelander brought Billy to his wife for some reason. Was it the same way in the comics? Why did he do so? And did relations of Homelander and Billy change after that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to fall under the Future Works policy. The motives of Homelander's action would be revealed in Season-2

Comment: @Shreedhar what is the Future Works reference? I know that 2nd season on the way, but I thought that people who read the comics may know the answers.

Comment: if you're looking for answers from the comics, I'd suggest you to change your question accordingly. Because you never know if the TV series would follow the comics at all or not.

Comment: To understand the Future Works policy, read this: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11865/what-are-future-works

Comment: @Shreedhar I changed it as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this did not happen in the comics. In the comics, [Butcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Boys_characters#Billy_Butcher) directly witnessed his wife's death.

> Following a strange period of emotional distance between the two of them, Butcher awoke to find his wife disemboweled on their bed, with her prematurely born, superpowered child floating above her; after it attacked Butcher with its heat vision, he killed it by beating it to death with a lampstand.

He believed that The Homelander was responsible for this, but later learns the truth.

> At the final clash in Washington, Butcher learned that it was Black Noir who'd killed his wife rather than Homelander, and he finally gained his revenge.

Comment: Why didn't he think that the boy killed his wife?

Comment: @RS: Long story short, it was Black Noir, dressed as Homelander, who'd raped his wife.